# Template for custom post type shows all posts instead of just one

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, loop, templates

I wrote a simple plugin to create a custom post type named "people":

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_person' );

function create_person() {
    register_post_type( 'people',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => 'People',
                'singular_name' => 'Person',
                'add_new' => 'Add New',
                'add_new_item' => 'Add New Person',
                'edit' => 'Edit',
                'edit_item' => 'Edit Person',
                'new_item' => 'New Person',
                'view' => 'View',
                'view_item' => 'View Person',
                'search_items' => 'Search People',
                'not_found' => 'No person found',
                'not_found_in_trash' => 'No people found in trash',
                'parent' => 'Parent Person'
            ),

            'public' => true,
            'menu_position' => null,
            'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'comments', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields' ),
            'taxonomies' => array( '' ),
            'menu_icon' => plugins_url( 'images/people_icon.png', __FILE__ ),
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'show_ui' => true, 
            'show_in_menu' => true, 
            'query_var' => true,
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'people','with_front' => FALSE),
            'capability_type' => 'post',
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'has_archive' => true
        )
    );
}
```

And added a template called single-person.php to display the custom post type. This filter is in the same file as the code above:

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'include_template_people', 1 );

function include_template_people( $template_path ) {
    if ( get_post_type() == 'people' ) {
        if ( is_single() ) {
            // checks if the file exists in the theme first,
            // otherwise serve the file from the plugin
            if ( $theme_file = locate_template( array ( 'single-people.php' ) ) ) {
                $template_path = $theme_file;
            } else {
                $template_path = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/single-people.php';
            }
        }
    }
    return $template_path;
}
```

Then there is the actual template here:

```
<?php
 /*Template Name: New Template
 */

get_header(); ?>
<div id="primary">

    <div id="content" role="main">
    <?php
    $mypost = array( 'post_type' => 'people', );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $mypost );
    ?>
    <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();?>
        <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
            <div class="person">
                <div class="person-header">
                    <div class="person-image">
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail( array( 300, 300 ) ); ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="person-name"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
                    <div class="roles-list">
                        <?php echo get_the_term_list( $id, 'roles', '', ', ', '' ); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="person-content"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
            </div>
        </article>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

UPDATED:

I changed the question a bit. I removed a piece of code that I had added. The problem with this template is that when I go to the URL:

```
mysite.com/people/firstname-lastname
```

I expect to only get the post of type 'people' which has the slug "firstname-lastname". Instead, all the posts of type 'people' show up on the page. How can I change this so that only the single 'post' is displayed?

Comment: Which is the value of $id in args array?

Comment: What _does_ post ID 221 correspond to? Check the database for that ID.

Comment: 221 corresponds to a "post" that is unrelated.

Comment: iEmanuele, I'm not sure I understand your question. 221 is the value $id is set to after the loop is over. Inside the loop it should be set to 106, but apparently it is empty inside the loop.

Comment: in `$mypost = array( 'post_type' => 'people', 'post__in' => array( $id ) );` where the `$id` variable come from?

Comment: I don't know. I figured it was set by the the wordpress core or something. I think that I added the 'post__in' => array( $id ) myself. The example I was going off of did not use it. When I remove that part and use the line:

$mypost = array( 'post_type' => 'people', );

It displays all of the "people" post types, not just the one I was trying to display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the code for the 'actual template' you posted is in the `single-people.php`...

**you do not need any query at all**!

When you call the url `mysite.com/people/firstname-lastname` wordpress already know that you want to view that person, only search for a file that *display* it.

Normally, wordpress, in this case, search for the file **single-people.php** in the theme folder and if don't find it, than search for `single.php` and so on, following [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy).

Your plugin modify this behavior, so if no `single-people.php` file is the theme folder, instead of searching for `single.php` in theme now wordpress search for `single-people.php` in your plugin folder.

So, again, if the file come from `single-people.php` you have not to put here any query at all to use the standard main wp query that is, in this case, just showing the post.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="primary">
<div id="content" role="main">
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
        <div class="person">
            <div class="person-header">
                <div class="person-image">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail( array( 300, 300 ) ); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="person-name"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
                <div class="roles-list">
                    <?php echo get_the_term_list( get_the_ID(), 'roles', '', ', ', '' ); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="person-content"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
        </div>
    </article>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you very much. I knew there was some basic thing I was missing.