# Changing the default header name

Tags: security

Is it possible to change the default header.php file to something else for security reasons? It seems header.php is target for malicious attacks.

I know all that, we have different named headers, I am talking about the default one. For example instead of header.php rename it to imcool.php and I don't appreciate the negative point. All the default files index.php, admin as a user, header are always targets for malicious attacks including injection.

Comment: What kind of attacks?

Comment: There is no security problem with `header.php`.

Comment: I fail to see the security benefits of renaming that file, unless your `header.php` if very poorly written but if that is the case it needs to be rewritten not hidden.

Comment: See my edited text.

Comment: Aaahh. I'm starting to understand what kind of attacks you're talking about, I guess. Do you mean some viruses that will modify your files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

You can name this file whatever you want. In this case, you should use `get_template_part` instead of `get_header` to include this file in other templates.

Or you can name it `header-something.php` and then use `get_header('something')`.

PS. I hope I haven't misunderstood your question.

Comment: Though any file that uses `get_header()`, say a template file included by a plugin, will not work correctly.

Comment: @s_ha_dum Yes, that is the problem. Do you know any plugins that include theme files?

Comment: I have seen a few. The idea is to provide a default template for some specialized data. [This recent question on WPSE](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/108340/21376) is attempting the same.

Comment: As long as wp_head is present, everything will work. Thanks Krzy, I will try your idea.

Comment: @NikolaosVassos well, not exactly. If a plugin will call `get_header` and your theme doesn't have one, you'll get some problems.

Comment: @s_ha_dum I guess these plugins are making wrong assumptions. `header.php` is not required in your theme. So there is a chance that some themes won't have this file. (Although again, I haven't seen many such themes...)

Comment: The whole website is ran by a custom plugin, easily changeable.

Comment: If the theme has no `header.php` a [default file is loaded](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-includes/general-template.php#L35) so I don't think there is a problem with the assumptions but either way if `header.php` is renamed the wrong header file will load.

Answer (score 1):

Split your file to whatever name you want to denote, i.e. `xyz.php`.

So, just *include* the page with:

```
<?php get_template_part('xyz'); ?>
```

Or, `my-xyz.php`:

```
<?php get_template_part('my', 'xyz'); ?>
```

It's that simple.